# Mule dynamic property file reference

Tags: mule, mule-component

we have a flow where we have property file reference as given below

```
"context:property-placeholder location="httpdemo.${country}.properties"
```

now we want `${country}` value to be replaced by actual value at the time of deployment.

As we know one way to achieve it is setting the value of country as environment variable on the ESB and deploying it. But we don’t want to do that because of below reasons:

1. We deploy same code base for multiple countries in parallel
2. Environment properties can be set only during start of mule runtime so if I set env variable as `country=UK` and have deployed for UK. Later I want to deploy for MY again I need to restart ESB by setting `country=MY` which we don’t want to do.

Please let me know if there is any other better way

Comment: The example you've given either contains too much quotes or too few quotes if you added them for the StackOverflow. Please edit and fix it with code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation where we needed to have multiple versions of the same application running parallely. The solution we used for this was to package the property file along with the build and not have the dynamic element (environment based) to it. For eg; in this case we construct httpdemo.usa.properties and packaged it along with the app. This was fairly easy for us since we use Jenkins to manage our builds and releases. When the build is released, we reference a configuration file from Jenkins which contains all the specific "country" related properties. You can even pass this country as a parameter to the build definition. Using a custom maven plugin we replace the property file within the app with the new properties from the Jenkins property file.

Another solution to your problem could be to follow a naming convention to your apps specific to the "country" you want to use and fetch the properties using spring beans. For eg;

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="CountryProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="singleton" value="true"/>
        <spring:property name="location" value="${app.name}.properties"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="5000" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="dynamic_propsFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[app.registry.CountryProperties['country.full.name']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

My properties are like below:

```
File - dynamic_props_usa.properties
population=10
country.full.name=united.states.of.america

File - dynamic_props_mexico.properties
population=100
country.full.name=mexico
```

${app.name} gives you the name of the app that is deployed. In case my app is named dynamic_props_usa, it refers the dynamic_props_usa.properties. If it is, dynamic_props_mexico, it refers dynamic_props_mexico.properties. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Define context property placeholder to have a file reference in the package and have an option to override the same with server if needed at runtime as below,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app-${mule.env}.properties,    file:${mule.config.path}/app-${mule.env}.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run your on premise Mule server with the option `-M-Dmule.country=your-value`

You may want to take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/deploying-to-multiple-environments)